# [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "upload-success": "TypeError: fns.apply is not a function"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using this [plugin](https://vuejsexamples.com/a-simple-upload-multiple-image-component-for-vuejs/) to upload images. But I'm getting this errors

> [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "upload-success": "TypeError:
>   fns.apply is not a function" found in --->  at
>   node_modules/vue-upload-multiple-image/src/components/VueUploadMultipleImage.vue
>    at
>   assets/frontend/js/components/VueUploadMultipleImages.vue

Here is my code,

```
<template>
    <div class="vue-upload-multiple-image" style='display: flex; justify-content: left;'>
        <vue-upload-multiple-image
                @upload-success='uploadImageSuccess'
                @before-remove='beforeRemove'
                @edit-image='editImage'
                @data-change='data_change'
                :dragText="dragText"
                :browseText="browseText"
                :dropText="dropText"
                :markIsPrimaryText="markIsPrimaryText"
                :popupText="popupText"
                :primaryText="primaryText"
                :data-images='images'>
        </vue-upload-multiple-image>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import VueUploadMultipleImage from 'vue-upload-multiple-image'
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default {
        name: 'uploader',
        data: function () {
            return {
                dragText: dragText,
                browseText: browseText,
                primaryText: primaryText,
                markIsPrimaryText: markIsPrimaryText,
                popupText: popupText,
                dropText: dropText,
                maxImage: maxImage,
                showPrimary: showPrimary,
                accept: 'image/gif,image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp,image/jpg',
                dataImages: [],
                multiple: true,
                images: [],
                uploadImageSuccess : '',
                beforeRemove: '',
                editImage : '',
            }
        },
        components: {
            VueUploadMultipleImage
        },
        methods: {
            data_change(data) {
                console.log(data);
                alert('asasa');
            }
        }
    }

new Vue({
    el: "#car-image-upload",
    components: {
        'uploader': VueUploadMultipleImages
    },
})
</script>

<div id="car-image-upload"><uploader></uploader></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `uploadImageSuccess` is set as a string, not a method.
You get the error because the **vue-upload-multiple-image** component tries to call it as a function.

Add a method to your component to handle the successful image upload:

```
...

methods: {
  uploadImageSuccess(formData, index, fileList) {
    // Do whatever you need here
  }
},

...
```

Note: you should do the same with `beforeRemove` and `editImage`

I hope this helps.

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped you out :)